# Performance of CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, cashapelayer

From apple's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/index.html) and [session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2010-425/),I think **CAShapeLayer** should render in **render server** when composited.And if **shouldRasterize** is disabled, the path should render every frame.

But when I profile a layer with a very complex path, seems not true. I can see the  render is not happen on app side, but it is not happen every frame when I disabled rasterize, it only happen when I change the path.

Apple now cache the rendered bitmap all the time, this may consume some memory?

If apple cache the bitmap, I think it's conflict with the session above.

Comment: If the server is caching the rendered path, then the cached image consumes memory. Why do you think that is a problem?

Comment: If apple cache the bitmap, I think it's conflict with the session above

Comment: Did you find any more info regarding how CAShapeLayer works at the render server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path rasterization process of the `CAShapeLayer` happens on the render server side, not on the client (app) side.

Comment: More detail will be better.